# Where is the phpMyAdmin config file on a Laradock/Docker installation?

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, config, laradock

I have successfully installed  Laradock/Docker (latest version) as well as phpMyAdmin on Mac Monterey.  Everything finally works smoothly, but I can not find the config file of phpMyAdmin to add external web servers.

On previous installations (not Laradock), the file phpmyadmin.config.inc.php was in usr/local/etc.

I tried to put the file there with an echo/exit command there but nothing happens.  I also tried to put the file in the laradock/phpMyAdmin folder... same result.

What is the solution to add external servers in a config file for phpMyAdmin?

EDIT
++++

The file **laradock/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php** was created by Docker.

Here is the volume in **docker-compose.yml**

```
phpmyadmin:
  build: ./phpmyadmin
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - MYSQL_USER=${PMA_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PMA_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${PMA_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=${PMA_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME}
    - MEMORY_LIMIT=${PMA_MEMORY_LIMIT}
    - UPLOAD_LIMIT=${PMA_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
  ports:
    - "${PMA_PORT}:80"
  volumes:
    - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
  depends_on:
    - "${PMA_DB_ENGINE}"
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

Comment: This question is quite specific to the Laradock implementation, you might get a better answer by going directly through their support channels (https://laradock.io/help/). They seem to have a Gitter chat room and are also open to questions through their GitHub issue interface.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I tried these channels before but with no success... so I was hoping someone here could help...

Comment: Add the config file in the phpmyadmin directory of your Laradock, then add that config file to the container through a volume in your `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: @UnderDog Thank you for getting back to me on that.  However, being quite new to Laradock, could you please confirm the following? In laradock/phpmyadmin, there is already a file called phpmyadmin.config.inc.php with lists all the mysql servers but that file is not taken into account.  What do I have to do in the docker-compose.yml to register that file?

Comment: Open your docker-compose.yml and find the volumes for phpmyadmin. Add        `- ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php` see if it works, phpmyadmin has changed in the last few years. If phpmyadmin doesn't have volumes yet, copy one from for example nginx and replace it with this one

Comment: @UnderDog I added the line "volumes: - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php" in the ### phpMyAdmin section, restarted phpMyAdmin in Docker Desktop but the external servers still do no show in the left panel of PMA.

Comment: Shit, I just now read that last line in your original question. See if the config file you attached through the volume is the actual file that is used. Change the number of rows (for example) that are shown. From 50 to ... 25? 100? If it's the actual file, let's continue there. Ways docker-compose down -v after you make such a change. Hope it's the right file

Comment: The file config.user.inc.php is in 3 folders on my mac: etc/phpmyadmin, sites/laradock/phpmyadmin and sites/laradock/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php (a folder that was created after docker-compose up -d apache2 mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace mailhog php-fpm).  In each file, I echo the location and exit.  When I start phpmyadmin in the browser (http://localhost:8081/), it seems that none of the files above are read.  I don't know what to do...

Comment: @UnderDog I still have not found a solution for that issue. Pleeeeeeze help.

Comment: >> `sites/laradock/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php (a folder that was created after ...` ====>>> that should have been a file, not a *folder*, so take a really close look at the volume in your `docker-compose.yml`. Update your original question with that contents for that volume... it should be a reproducible example

Comment: I have tried several things but nothing works... I have updated my question as @UnderDog suggested.

Comment: `- ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php` should be: `- ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php` I'll assume that's a copy/paste error. If that's true, I'll take a look this weekend, hoping that the rest is default 'laradock stuff'.

Comment: @UnderDog I have the impression we are turning in circles... Laradock creates a folder called "config.user.inc.php" with a file called "phpmyadmin.config.inc.php".  In non Laradock installation, the "config.user.inc.php" file containing my remote mysql servers was in etc/phpmyadmin.  None of these files are read by Docker at startup.  This is why, I try to change the path in the docker-compose.yml... but no success there!

Comment: I will take a look for you this weekend and will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

- make sure, that your docker containers are not running: `docker-compose down -v`
- go to your laradock/phpmyadmin directory, you will probably see a directory called `config.user.inc.php, go there
- you will probably see a *directory* called phpmyadmin.config.user.inc.php delete that directory *after* making sure you have a backup of your config file
  The directory should look like this screenshot
  [image: phpmyadmin settings (before changes)]
  And one more screenshot from the code editor:
  [image: directory-settings-phpmyadmin]

I've tested this setup with the following in the docker-compose file:

```
phpmyadmin:
  build: ./phpmyadmin
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - MYSQL_USER=${PMA_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PMA_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${PMA_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=${PMA_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME}
    - MEMORY_LIMIT=${PMA_MEMORY_LIMIT}
    - UPLOAD_LIMIT=${PMA_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
  ports:
    - "${PMA_PORT}:80"
  volumes:
    - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
  depends_on:
    - "${PMA_DB_ENGINE}"
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

and yes, that's exactly the same as your last updated docker-compose example in your original question

The thing I tested in my `phpmyadmin.config.inc.php` was, to change the `$cfg['MaxRows'] = 100;` and it worked.

**Advised changes and explanation**

- of course, take your containers down again: `docker-compose down -v`
- go to your laradock/phpmyadmin directory, you should see this directory:
  [image: just laradock directory]
- look in that directory using your mac file browser, there should be a phpmyadmin.config.inc.php file in there
- move that file one directory up. In Linux it's this command:
  `mv phpmyadmin.config.inc.php ..`
- go one directory up, you're now in the ~/laradock/phpmyadmin directory
- you'll have a *directory* of `config.user.inc.php` and a *file* of `phpmyadmin.config.inc.php`, see screenshot[image: directory contents]
- the goal is:
- to "remove" the directory `config.user.inc.php`
- to rename `phpmyadmin.config.inc.php` to `config.user.inc.php`
- to adjust `docker-compose.yml`

[] `rm -Rf config.user.inc.php` [image: remove directory]
[] `mv phpmyadmin.config.inc.php config.user.inc.php` [image: rename file]
Your directory structure should look like this:
[image]
[] adjust docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
      volumes:
        - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
```

bring your containers up again:

```bash
docker-compose up nginx mysql php-fpm phpmyadmin workspace -d
```

**Explanation**
In your `docker-compose.yml` file you had a volume like this:

```
  volumes:
    - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
```

If docker cannot find the file, it creates a *directory* with that filename, to make the volume. That is the reason why your changes didn't come through.
If you bring the container down again (volume down as well), that created directory doesn't get deleted.

The suggestion is to remove the `/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php` and place the `config.user.inc.php` file in the phpmyadmin directory (next to the Dockerfile)
If you correct your `docker-compose.yml` file and then do the `docker-compose up` it will add your volume with the correct file.

In the end I added this to the config file:
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'default|information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys';`
and the system tables are missing from my phpmyadmin screen:
[image: no system tables]

Comment: It worked 100%.  Thank you so much for spending the time to re-explain step by step! Have a good we.