# Laradock can't see files in workspace

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, laradock

Everything worked fine until I had to rebuild my images after rebuild I can no longer see my project files.

Laradock and project files are inside WSL2
/home/[username]/[project_name]
Laradock
Larvel

And I can see all files when I do ls inside WSL2 but when I exec to workspace I only see laradock folder and inside only couple other folders even though there's much more.

APP_CODE_PATH_HOST is set to ../ which looks like it's correct since I can see laradock folder also I created couple test folders inside same directory and chmod them to 777 after multiple restarts and rebuilds even deleting all volumes randomly my laravel and test folder appeared again there were more folders than that and when I cd into them they were empty.

While writing this question docker crashed and after restart I only see Laradock folder with couple image folders inside again. It looks like some kind of permission issue but can't wrap my head around it.

EDIT:
Just checked docker desktop app and it looks like mount is correct
[image]

When checking files it only shows few that exists in that folder
[image]

Comment: show the `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @UnderDog it is default laradock ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG ../:/var/www:cached. I only modified workspace and php-fpm docker file but same thing is with nginx where I didn't modified anything.

Comment: So if it's default laradock uou can place a .php file in a public directory. Place the function `phpinfo();` in that file. If you cannot access that file in that public directory, then your volume is messed up.

Comment: @UnderDog yup it didn't showed up tried to create with wsl and then windows same thing nothing appears. What should I do if my volume is messed up? I just tried deleting containers and volume again but after running docker-compose same thing happening.

Comment: Your laradock, did you install it in your WSL or on your windows? I'll try to find my answer i gave to someone else, some time ago and I'll link it here. It's also regarding volumes

Comment: @UnderDog laradock and project files are inside WSL. Just tried deleting images, volumes and running older project with laradock which also ran fine before and var/www is empty.

Comment: So this link is also regarding volumes, see if you get the general idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75560729/1294911 I had to delete volumes, remove files, etc. In your workspace container, as **which user** are you logging in?